# Evaluate $\int x\sqrt{(a^2 - x^2)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to find $$\int x\sqrt{(a^2 - x^2)}dx$$

I tried putting $x=a cos(t)$ but I ended up getting a very complicated expression, so any tips?

Comment: Integrate by parts to get rid of the $x$ factor and use the trigonometric substitution for the rest.

Comment: @GitGud Or simply a $u$ substitution.

Comment: @GammaFunction Or not even that... I missed the direct way. Thanks.

Comment: Use the substitution $u=x^2$.

Comment: That's the sort of problem that sadistic calculus instructors throw in with a bunch of others just after teaching trig substitution!

Answer (score 7):

**Hint** Let $u = a^2-x^2$. Then $du = -2x dx$...

Answer (score 5):

Let $y=a^2-x^2$ then $dy=-2xdx$ so 
$$-\frac{1}{2}\int  \sqrt{a^2-x^2} (-2x)dx=-\frac{1}{2}\int  \sqrt{y} dy
=-\frac{1}{3}y^\frac{3}{2}= =-\frac{1}{3}(a^2-x^2)^\frac{3}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$-\frac{1}{3}(a^2-x^2)^\frac{3}{2}$ is one of the origional function because $\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(-\frac{1}{3}(a^2-x^2)^\frac{3}{2}\bigg)=x\sqrt{a^2-x^2}.$

Why did I come up with it because $\int x\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx=\int\sqrt{a^2-x^2}d(x^2)=-\frac{1}{3}(a^2-x^2)^\frac{3}{2}$+C.

Comment: Maybe someone thought I guessed the answer at first sight....